# How do I repeat code for a certain case in a switch statement and not repeat it for others?

Tags: java

I am making a Text-Based Adventure game. In one room, I want to ask the player what to do, and if he goes through the door he/she moves to the next room. If he/she picks up the flashlight, the "what do you want to do?" question is repeated so they can go through the door after that. Here is my code:

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("What do you want to do? Type 'door' to go through the door or 'flashlight' to pick up the flashlight.");
                String roomOneAction = input.nextLine();

                switch(roomOneAction) {

                    case "flashlight":
                        System.out.println("Picked up flashlight.");
                        //repeat what do you want to do? question
                        break;

                    case "door":
                        System.out.println("You open the door.");
                        //continue plot, don't repeat question
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        // repeat what do you want to do? question
                        break;
                    }
                break;
```

With this code right now, it repeats the question for anything you type. I do not want this to happen if "door" is typed.

Also, how can I make it so that once the flashlight is picked up and the question is repeated, the flashlight can't be picked up a second time?

Comment: Second question: keep world state somewhere, e.g., "has the flashlight been picked up". More precisely, you need to track the location of the flashlight: is it on the user's person? Is it in a room? First: states have transition criteria that determine what may and/or can happen next. Right now it looks like you've coded yourself into a corner where supporting both the above will lead to some very messy, hard-to-maintain code. You might want to rethink how game state is stored, and how decisions about what can happen next are made.

Answer (score 1):

This might be close to what you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    private static boolean flashlightPicked = false;
    private static boolean doorEntered = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            int x = 1;
            switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out
                        .println("What do you want to do? Type 'door' to go through the door or 'flashlight' to pick up the flashlight.");
                String roomOneAction = input.nextLine();

                switch (roomOneAction) {

                case "flashlight" :
                    if(!flashlightPicked){
                        System.out.println("Picked up flashlight.");
                        flashlightPicked = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Already picked up flashlight!");
                    }
                    // repeat what do you want to do? question
                    break;

                case "door":
                    if(!doorEntered){
                        System.out.println("You open the door.");
                        doorEntered = true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Already opened the door!");
                    }
                    // continue plot, don't repeat question
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    // repeat what do you want to do? question
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In stead of `private static`, main should create a `new Game()` and let it do the work.

Comment: How is the plot continued in the `door` case? Because of the `while (true)`, the swtich statement is entered again (and again).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should probably store the information if you want to ask again or not:

```
boolean askAgain = true;
//...
case "door":
    //...
    askAgain = false;
//...
if (askAgain) {
    System.out.println("...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a while loop here. Can the player do anything else in the room or leave the room in a different way? If they can only leave the room using the 'door' command, set up the while loop to have the terminating factor being the 'door' command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of cascading multiple switches as you did. You should use [**state pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and [**command pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), but I assume you're a programming beginner, so I'll just try to answer your question.

---

Wrap the `roomOneAction` switch statement in a while loop, like

```java
boolean foundFlashlight = false;
boolean askAgain = true;
while (askAgain)
{
  // question + switch statement and so on
}
```

if the player picks the flashflight, set `foundFlashlight` to `true`.

In the next run, the player gets asked again. If he picks flashlight,
you have to evaluate the `foundFlashlight` variable, if the value is `true`,
tell the player he already has the flashlight and he should answer again.

In the door case, simply set `askAgain` to `false.` The loop while terminate then.

---

But again, this is **not** a nice, clean and easy to maintain approach. You should take a look at some **design patterns**. Especially the above mentioned state pattern.